# text on canvas looks rubbish in IE...why?

Tags: html, canvas

i recently extended the lovely jquery "flot" charts plugin a bit...goal is to draw what would usually be in the legend directly on the chart.

it looks only a bit rubbish as IE seems to render the font quite weakly.

see here, left side is IE, right side is Firefox:

[issue http://i56.tinypic.com/34oq4ci.png](http://i56.tinypic.com/34oq4ci.png)

btw...function to draw the text used is fillText()

how can i whip IE into shape?

thanks!

Comment: what font are you using? for ctx.font?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you comparing to? Is it possibly just the move away from aggressively hinted fonts, as mentioned on sites like http://www.geekm.ag/Archive/Font_Purity_Firefox4_IE9_and_Direct2D_a_love_story ?

Comment: It's no fancy font, just normal Arial 11px in #ffffff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sad fact is that, as of now font discrepancies between all the browsers exist in Canvas. What looks one way in Firefox will look another way in IE. What looks one way in Chrome will look another way in Safari (even though they are both webkit based)

Change the font to a "safer" one and see what happens. For instance:

```
ctx.font = "72pt verdana"
ctx.fillText("lalalala", 0, 72);
```

Ought to render the same in both IE9 and FF4.

That isn't the last of it of course. If you are doing things like scaling and rotating your fonts you'll encounter even weirder problems. Try this in Opera or the non-dev version of Chrome: http://simonsarris.com/misc/scaleText.html

([screenshot of that problem](http://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=2833897286992020829&name=Capture.PNG&token=377e4d448884aa638a020d6c8e8aa9c9&inline=1))

So the solution is to simply find a font that ends up looking the same on the browsers you want to target (by trial and error, start with the web-safe font list), and try to never both scale *and* rotate the canvas before calling fillText. There may even be other transformations that cause odd effects in different browsers, so you should try your font on a simple case and see if it does truly look different.

Comment: So....I've kept Arial as font, got rid of the bold and forked it so that IE renders the font a bit bigger with 12px and all the other browsers with 11px and it kinda looks allright-ish....still a bit rubbish in IE but ok.